# How to get name of the argument in lua?

Tags: lua

I have lua function which accept the arguments. I want to get the name of the argument so that I can log the argument along with error.

Any idea how to get argument name in lua?

Comment: How come you don't know parameter name inside the function? If you don't, how you refer to them?

Comment: He probably doesn't want to repeat himself in the method arguments and in the logging, e.g. function f(firstname) print("firstname is " .. firstname)... When someone switches the variable name it might not get switched in the string literal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [debug.getlocal](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getlocal).

Comment: Very cool didn't know of this. Deleting my answer because I was wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If I have `local foo, bar = 2, 3; PrintVariable(bar, foo)`, how can I print variable name along with its value in function `PrintVariable()`?

Comment: @jdhao, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743935/lua-how-to-use-debug-getlocal