# Lua: how to use debug.getlocal

Tags: lua

```
local function ThisIsAFunction()
    local test1 = "im a local var"
    local asd = "im also a local var"
end
```

How would I use debug.getlocal to get the value of the local functions inside "ThisIsAFunction"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
local function printLocals()
  local i = 1
  while true do
    local name, value = debug.getlocal(2, i)
    if not name then break end
    print(name, i, value)
    i = i + 1
  end
end

local function ThisIsAFunction()
  local test1 = "im a local var"
  local asd = "im also a local var"
  printLocals()
end

ThisIsAFunction()
```

This should print:

```
test1   1   im a local var
asd 2   im also a local var
```

Note that `getlocal` can only get values for the function/frame that is already on the stack (that's why you need to call `printLocals` from the function you want to inspect).

You can use `getinfo` to inspect the function (from outside), but you need to be executing the function to inspect, so you need to make an explicit call to `printLocals` or use a debug hook to do an implicit one.

Comment: Can you come with an example where you use getinfo to get the values because I'm totally lost in this area and I can't find any documentation about it?
and I just tried but I can only manage to get info about the function and not the variables inside it.

```
local function ThisIsAFunction()
 local test1 = "im a local var"
 local asd = "im also a local var"
end

local a = debug.getinfo(ThisIsAFunction)

function table.print( tbl )
 for k,v in pairs( tbl ) do
  print( k, v )
 end
end

table.print(a)
```

Comment: You can't use `getinfo` to get local variables, but you can get some other information about the function. Here is the [documentation for getinfo](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo). What you have in your example should work.